# What does “sayd” (etc.) mean in old book clipping?

Tags: meaning, orthography, early-modern-english

Quotation from [A history of the cries of London ancient](http://archive.org/details/historyofcriesof00hind) (p24, 25).

[image]

Noisy parties of wits and **Paul**'s men crossed to Bankside to see *Romeo and Juliet*, *or Hamlet the Dane*, or else 'The most excellent **historie** of the *Merchant of Venice*, with the extreme **crueltie** of *Shylocke*, the **Jewe**, towards the **sayd** merchant, in cutting a just pound of his flesh, and obtaining of Portia by the **choyse** of three caskets, as it **hath** diverse times been acted by the **Lord Chamberlain**, his servants. Written by William Shakespeare.'

Comment: I'd guess it translates directly to "toward the said merchant" - meaning aforementioned.

Comment: Good for ELL. Voting to close as GR.

Comment: One question per post, please. I took out the extraneous bits.

Comment: Maybe not good for ELL but certainly General Reference.

Answer (score 1):

It's an archaic spelling of *said*.  Here, it means *aforementioned*.  This usage of *said* is less common today, but it is still in use.

(Your other two questions weren't really appropriate for *English Language & Usage*, so they were deleted.)

Comment: Thanks. Then, What does “his servants” mean, like “His Majesty”？

Comment: @pit i took out the extraneous questions, in case you'd like to edit

Comment: @user25049: I think it means "the Lord Chamberlain's servants".